# Flow - 'For a selected file' trigger not populating Dynamic Content

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, flow

Previously I've created several flows that are all triggered from SharePoint libraries, all beginning the same way.  The trigger is "For a selected file" immediately followed by a "Get file properties" action.  In the past, the dynamic content from the trigger was available in the action, so I could use the ID of the selected file to get the file properties.

Now, when I try to make a new Flow, the Dynamic Content is missing in the Get file properties action. If I access one of the Flows I'd created previously, the Dynamic Content is "missing" there, too. (Luckily the field is still there, and the Flows still work).

Moreover, if I choose a different action (e.g. Send me an email notification), the Dynamic Content from the trigger populates just fine.

**So how can I get the file properties for a selected file?** Do I have to use a different trigger/action combination? Can I use an expression of some sort as a work-around? Any suggestions are appreciated!

***Current:*** 
[image: Current]

***Other action (same flow):***
[image: Other]

***Flow created previously (DC used to be there, but no longer):***
[image: Old Flow]

Comment: Temporary Workarounds I've been using include taking an existing flow and Saving As to create a copy I can then gut except this part (luckily for the same library).  I've also successfully copy-pasted the ID field from one Flow to another.  Does not solve the problem, though, I'm still unable to select dynamic content in the Get File Properties action of new and existing flows.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to change the trigger type from "For a selected file" to "For a selected item", which allows us to use the ID again.  This trigger will work fine with Document Libraries, but you will need to enter the library name manually in the "List Name" field:

[image]

I don't know why it no longer works with "For a selected file".  I guess there's a chance Microsoft will fix it in due time...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that the library you trying to do this in has Document Sets enabled.  Flow does not work well with Docsets while Microsoft is "modernizing".  Your old Flows probably work because they were setup before changes made by Microsoft or on Libraries that did not have Docsets.

Try using an HTTP request as a trigger or use Sharepoint Designer with a classic workflow.  The classic workflow can probably be set to trigger your modern flow.

[Here](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2019/04/17/microsoft-flow-and-document-sets-while-waiting-for-modernization/) is a more thorough explanation.